# Why was meta-crisis Doctor dangerous?

Tags: doctor-who

From Doctor Who episode *Journey's End* [transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/30-13.htm):

> ROSE: No, but I spent all that time trying to find you. I'm not going back now.
>   DOCTOR: But you've got to. Because we saved the universe, but at a cost. And the cost is him. He destroyed the Daleks. He committed genocide. **He's too dangerous to be left on his own.**
>   NEW DOCTOR: You made me.
>   DOCTOR: Exactly. You were born in battle, full of blood and anger and revenge. Remind you of someone? That's me, when we first met. And you made me better. Now you can do the same for him.
>   ROSE: But he's not you.
>   DOCTOR: He needs you. That's very me.
>   DONNA: But it's better than that, though. Don't you see what he's trying to give you? Tell her. Go on.
>   NEW DOCTOR: I look like him and **I think like him. Same memories, same thoughts, same everything.** Except I've only got one heart.

Maybe, the meta-crisis Doctor was born in battle, but he had full memories of The Doctor which includes the time he spent with Rose. Why was Rose needed again to make him better? Weren't memories enough? I mean, wasn't he already a better Doctor than his pre-Rose existence?

Comment: The clear implication is that because he's human (but with the memories of a timelord) he's lacking in the discipline and self-control of that species. I'm not sure how much clearer that could be said without simply quoting the quote back to you.

Comment: @Richard Then, how could The Doctor compare his own betterment (by Rose) with this?

Comment: He's too dangerous to be left without the stabilising influence of Rose.

Comment: From a certain point of view, he's talking about himself.  The regular Doctor also committed genocide by destroying the Daleks and The Time Lords (later retconned).  The "regular" Doctor ALSO should not be left alone.

Comment: What? There is zero evidence that the doctor implied anything regarding the anger coming from being part human. ...

Comment: Just imagine [this being](http://media.tumblr.com/9deb904cb147dcc85a07b0a934793d17/tumblr_inline_mrcuor85zy1qz4rgp.gif) with the self control of a human.

Answer (score 3):

The meta-crisis Doctor was dangerous because he would go to the extent of genocide, while the current Doctor wouldn't.

Let's try to think of it in another fashion, if he was EXACTLY the same and memories were enough do you think that the Meta Crisis Doctor would have actually committed genocide?  What actually happened was that this new Doctor was also half human and therefore he was different in that regard to the original Doctor.

Since the Meta-Crisis Doctor was born in battle, even though he shared all the same memories of the original Doctor he still needed somebody to guide him to be a better person.

Another point is that the Meta Crisis Doctor wasn't necessarily a better person pre-Rose existence, if this was true he would have found a way to defeat Davros without killing the majority of The Daleks.  Either way one of the other main reasons The Doctor left Rose with Meta Crisis Doctor was so that he could give Rose a "normal" life, in which they both grow old together.

Answer (score 1):

If you remenber the 9th Doctor, he loose himself when he encontered the Dalek in the chapter "Dalek" awaking his soldier-self, and that self where about to kill all the humanity and the Dalks in the end of that season, but when he meet Rose, he began to change, little by little. The Metacrisis-Doctor never meet Rose, so he is still a mercy-less Time Lord. But the thing is that the Doctor without a companion is uncontrollable, like the 12 Doctor in the 8 season, Clara asked "How much time have you been on your own...?" or something like that. It's like he put himself a restrain infront of a human. Also, he is a TimeLord Human: mix the power and inteligence of a Time Lord and add it to a mentally unestable, noisy, and cruel human body.

Comment: _"The Metacrisis-Doctor never meet Rose"_  of course he did.  He has all the "real" Doctor's memories, as he said himself in OP's quote.

Comment: Yeah, I think that would be a Russell T. Davies blunder. But I think that that would be a un-restrained Doctor without a companion, or something like that